# How to replace a specific character in regex?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to find a `/` symbol on given text and replace with `*` symbol.

`http://localhost:7070/home/test/mobile:device.testdevice.id1_123.id2_456.id3_ab-c.CONSTANT_formula:map/TreeMap.json`

Here the CONSTANT is fixed and it will not get changed but after CONSTANT there can be any character. I want find the CONSTANT in the url and look for `/` symbol and replace it with `*` symbol.

Something like this - `http://localhost:7070/home/test/mobile:device.testdevice.id1_123.id2_456.id3_ab-c.CONSTANT_formula:map*TreeMap.json`

I am trying with below regular expression but it matches everything after CONSTANT as I use one or more identifier

```
^CONSTANT(.+)
```

Is there any way find the / symbol and replace with * symbol?

Comment: Do you mean like `s/CONSTANT/*/g`

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I want to replace this CONSTANT_formula:map/TreeMap.json with CONSTANT_formula:map*TreeMap.json

Comment: @anubhava - I want to do this apache RewriteRule. First I want to complete the regex and have it in RewriteRule

Comment: But why do you want to have `*` in place of `/` in your URIs?

Comment: Which programing language do you prefer?

Comment: Pylon - I want to perform this in apache RewriteRule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mod_rewrite` rule you can do this to replace `/` with `*` after keyword `CONSTANT`:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*CONSTANT[^/]*)/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1*%2 [L,NE,R]
```

Note that it will perform an external redirect after replacement in URL.

We are using 2 capture groups in `RewriteCond`:

1. `^(/.*CONSTANT[^/]*)` matches everything upto `CONSTANT` followed by 0 or more of any char that is not `/`
2. Then we match `/`
3. `(.*)`: Finally we match everything else in 2nd capture group

Comment: Thank you anubhava. can we test the reg online ? I tried with regex101 but there is no flavor for apace.

Comment: yeah, my intention was to accept the regex

Comment: It works well in my local apache anubhava. thank you so much. I have two question, 1) I tried without [R] but it is not working. can we make this work without [R]? 2) tried without [L] and it worked well. Any reason why we should have [L], maybe is it good practice?

Comment: Yes `L` is for good practice as it marks it as `LAST` rule before `mod_rewrite` loop runs again. `R` is for external redirect so without `R` flag you will not see change of URL without this flag (it will be internal only).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, one last question, I want to support mutiple "/" symbol. For now it supports only one / symbol. Is there way to handle more than one "/" symbol ? It may have 1 or more slash.

Comment: It supports multiple `/`s. Only issue is that it will redirect as many times as the number of `/`s. But finally it will make `CONSTANT_formula:foo/bar/map/TreeMap.json` into `CONSTANT_formula:foo*bar*map*TreeMap.json`

Comment: ohh yeah, it works for multiple "/" slashes. Now I understood that it keep checking the slash and until it replace everything. Great. Quick question - I already have L rewrite rule in rewrite file, I hope I can not have more than one LAST. Can you tell me if there is way to solve this?

Comment: Every rule can have `L` flag separately. `L` is to force mod_rewrite to run the loop again

Answer (score 1):

By using JavaScript, just use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Let the regex seperates the string into two parts from `CONSTANT`. Replace all `/` to `*` in the latter one.

```js
const reg = /CONSTANT(.*)/g
const s = "http://localhost:7070/home/test/mobile:device.testdevice.id1_123.id2_456.id3_ab-c.CONSTANT_formula:map/dir1/dir2/TreeMap.json"
const fixedStr = s.replace(reg, (match, g1, idx, origStr) => {
    return origStr.slice(0, idx) + match.replace(/\//g, '*');
});
console.log(fixedStr)
```

Comment: It won't really replace more than one `/` after `CONSTANT` as desired by OP. For example if URL ends with `CONSTANT_formula:map/dir/TreeMap.json` it won't replace both `/` with `*`

Comment: Yeah, it works for JS but for Apache rewrite